# Navigation menu with submenu not staying highlighted

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS and HTML code for my navigation menu, as you can see when you hover over one of the main links it goes orange. but then when you go over a link on the sub menu, the orange disappears.

how can you keep it so it stays orange when you go on the sub menu link?

```
<ul id="trans-nav">
<li>
<a href="#">About Us</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="/contact">Contact Us</a></li>
<li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

#trans-nav {
    list-style-type: none; 
    height: 40px; 
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 0;
    position:relative;
    z-index:999;
}
#trans-nav {
    list-style-type: none; 
    height: 40px; 
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 0;
}
#trans-nav li {
    float: left; 
    position: relative; 
    padding: 0; 
    line-height: 40px;
}
#trans-nav li:hover {
    background-position: 0 -40px;
}
#trans-nav li a {
    display: block; 
    padding: 0 15px; 
    color: #666666; 
    text-decoration: none;
}
#trans-nav li a:hover {
    background-color:#F36F25; 
    color: #eeeeee;
}
#trans-nav li ul {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
    background: #EEEEEE;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0; 
}
#trans-nav li:hover ul {
    opacity: 1; 
}
#trans-nav li ul li {
    float: none; 
    position: static; 
    height: 0; 
    line-height: 0; 
    background: none;
}
#trans-nav li:hover ul li {
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
}
#trans-nav li ul li a {
    background: #EEEEEE;
}
#trans-nav li ul li a:hover {
    background: #666666;
    color:#EEEEEE;
}

#trans-nav li { -webkit-transition: all 0.2s; }
#trans-nav li a { -webkit-transition: all 0.5s; }
#trans-nav li ul { -webkit-transition: all 1s; }
#trans-nav li ul li { -webkit-transition: height 0.5s; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/wjy74/

```
#trans-nav:hover {
 background-color:#F36F25; 
 color: #eeeeee;
 width: 89px;    
}
```

Comment: This is an alternative if you want to keep the main item colorful while selecting a subitem.

Comment: how can i do it on my current coode?